# Cannot set java port for discord bot on Heroku

Tags: java, heroku

I have written a discord bot using the javacord library and it works very well because if I run the program in IntelliJ idea, the bot is online on Discord (and I can use it).

When I upload the bot to heroku, I can use it for a few minutes and then I get these errors:

```
2019-02-04T22:21:01.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user aa@aa.com

2019-02-04T22:21:15.414268+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

2019-02-04T22:21:19.806474+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -jar warbot.jar -server.port=22270`

2019-02-04T22:21:14.200586+00:00 app[api]: Deploy dc88e3ab by user aa@aa.com

2019-02-04T22:21:22.813747+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.

2019-02-04T22:21:22.825641+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 

2019-02-04T22:21:23.528694+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-02-04 22:21:23.469+0000 INFO org.javacord.core.util.logging.ExceptionLoggerDelegateImpl No Log4j2 compatible logger was found. Using default Javacord implementation!

2019-02-04T22:21:27.268649+00:00 app[web.1]: The bot has started

2019-02-04T22:21:14.200586+00:00 app[api]: Release v25 created by user aa@aa.com

2019-02-04T22:21:24.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded

2019-02-04T22:22:50.697048+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2019-02-04T22:22:50.530237+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch

2019-02-04T22:22:50.530363+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL

2019-02-04T22:22:50.678651+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

Basically, after a few the bot crashes. How can I fix this?

---

Many answers online mention the Spring framework but I am not using it! And the solution that involves `-Dspring.server.port=$PORT` does not work. I have this in my Procfile:

> web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar warbot.jar -server.port=$PORT

Where `warbot.jar` is the jar in the same location as the Procfile (which is in the root). How can I fix this? It seems that the above line is not enough to set the port.

I basically have to set the PORT so that heroku does not complain and my bot can stay online!

Comment: Actually, you are using spring. It is a dependency implicitly through javacord. If you run mvn dependency:tree you will see this.

Comment: i think you might need `--server.port` (note the two dashes)

Comment: @Frozendragon thank you, I am running a test with `web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar warbot.jar -Dspring.server.port=$PORT $JAR_OPTS` to see if it works

Comment: @codefinger well I'll do a test with `web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar warbot.jar --server.port=$PORT $JAR_OPTS` to see what happens